# RabbitMQ On Ubuntu 14.04 Server Configuration

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, pika

I had this problem both on Amazon EC2 and on another VPS from another company that I could not access the rabbitmq server from outside to use the 5672 port for connecting to the server. in both cases the command :

```
telnet <ip> 5672
```

returnes this:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

and simple hellow world code example in python using pika library:

```
 import pika


credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'password')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('<ip>', 5672, "/",  credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"
connection.close()
```

throws this exception :

```
No handlers could be found for logger "pika.adapters.base_connection"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../Send.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('<ip>', 5672, "/",  credentials))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 61, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 513, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 804, in _connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 138, in _adapter_connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 120, in _adapter_connect
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: 2.0
```

on ec2 I allowed TCP,ICMP,UDP on all security groups on all instances ports ( for test purpose)  and did a simple installation explained in [this tutorial](http://karlgrz.com/rabbitmq-highly-available-queues-and-clustering-using-amazon-ec2/) ,
I could successfully create a two node cluster of rabbitmq on ec2, but I was not  able to access any of the cluster nodes from outside, regarding allowing access on all ports, still the same telnet result, I also enabled the management plugin, issuing:

```
wget <ip>:15672
```

on ec2 instances saved an HTML file meaning that the management plugin was working and accessible from each node. I used private IP addresses in /etc/hosts to make nodes find each other in /etc/hosts.

I decided to install a simple rabbitmq server on a ubuntu 14.04 vps, this time my purpose was only to make the access possible, what I did was pretty much the work flow explained [in here](https://marcqualie.com/2012/12/install-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-12.04) and everything worked on the server locally but still the same problem explained in the beginning.

disabling ubuntu firewall 
with :

```
# ufw disable
```

and issuing the command :

```
# iptables -F
```

in order to remove the firewall or iptable from issuing any problem did not help.
I can't think of any additional configuration that I should make to have access from outside to rabbitmq server, any idea?

thanks.

here is my rabbitmq.config :

```
[
{kernel,
[{inet_dist_listen_min, 45000},
{inet_dist_listen_max, 45000}
]
}
].
```

in my ec2 security configs :

```
All ICMP 0.0.0.0/0 everywhere
ALL TCP 0.0.0.0/0 everywhere
ALL UDP 0.0.0.0/0 everywhere
```

and SSH on port 22.

## Update & Another Scenario :

I am really struggling with this issue and in order to document my question more specifically, in case of a single ubuntu 14.04 instance I tried to access a single rabbitmq server instance on EC2 from my personal computer, this must not be that hard :( here are more information available for the case explained :

Ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance security group settings :
[image: my ec2 security group configuration]

my **/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf** file :

```
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=<instance private ip taken from ifconfig = 177.31.*.*>
```

my **/etc/hosts**  file :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.31.*.* ip-172-31-*-*
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

my `netstat -vpln` command output :

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0        0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      927/sshd        
tcp        0      0        172.31.*.*:5672      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4662/beam      
tcp        0      0        0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4662/beam      
tcp        0      0        0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2089/epmd      
tcp6       0      0        :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      927/sshd        
udp        0      0        0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           501/dhclient    
udp        0      0        0.0.0.0:45419           0.0.0.0:*                           501/dhclient    
udp6       0      0        :::61763                :::*                                501/dhclient
```

but whenever from my personal computer I perform :

```
$ telnet <instance public IP >  5672

Trying 54.86.*.*
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I've set the `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` to `0.0.0.0` and still no success. 
(i have also posted this scenario to the rabbitmq [mailing list here](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Connecting-To-Rabbitmq-Server-On-Ubuntu-14-04-EC2-Instance-From-Outside-td35459.html) )

Comment: can you add your security group settings from ec2 to your question? also your rabbitmq conf file?

Comment: @jpsf I have added what you asked at the end, thanks

Comment: can you access rabbitmq from the same machine where it is installed? for example if you substitute `<ip>` with `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.
I found the problem was my VPN. In my case I used Kerio on my local ubuntu machine, the minute I exited the kerio server I could telnet to my server.

it is a good tips to check the following :
-your firewall
-your connection ( in my case Kerio VPN was causing issues)